# Convert DatePicker to DateTime and to store in db

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a DatePicker property in my Viewmodel that is bound to my datepicker and in my model I have a DateTime property that stores the selected date,How do I convert the DatePicker to DateTime?

I've been playing around with it all morning and can't find the right solution, when I change the Viewmodel Datepicker property to DateTime the view displays the DatePicker as 01/01/0001

View

```
<DatePicker  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="txtDate"  Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" SelectedDate="{Binding Date,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
  public DatePicker Date
    {
        get { return Date = stock.Date; }
        set { stock.Date = value.SelectedDate.Value; }
    }
```

Model

```
 private DateTime _dateTime;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _dateTime;
        }


        set { _dateTime = value; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DatePicker is a control, it doesn't belong in your view model, it should only be in your view. Your view model should have a DateTime property that the DatePicker's SelectedDate property is bound to.

View

```
<DatePicker  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="txtDate"  Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" SelectedDate="{Binding Date,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

VM

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return Date = stock.Date; }
    set { stock.Date = value; }
}
```

Comment: Ya that is the way I had it and it worked but it displays the datepicker as 01/01/0001 and doesn't display any proper dates?

Comment: What's the initial value of stock.Date?

Comment: Thank you Sir,it's working correctly now,much appreciated